# Send email with attachments with Mailgun

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2, mailgun

I'm integrating Mailgun into my iOS app, and am trying to send an email with an attachment. The email gets sent, however the attachment appears to be ignored. Any ideas? The code is below. I'm using AFNetworking 2, and I don't use the the native Mailgun Objective-C SDK, since it doesn't appear to be maintained.

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api:%@@api.mailgun.net/v3/%@/messages", kTIXMailgunAPIKey, kTIXMailgunDomain];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[ @"text/plain", @"text/html", @"application/json" ] ];

NSData *attachment = [attachments firstObject];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"from"            : fromAddress,
                             @"to"              : toAddress,
                             @"subject"         : @"Inline",
                             @"text"            : @"Email body",
                             @"content-type"    : @"multipart/form-data",
                             @"attachment"      : attachment,
                             };
[manager POST:path
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Success sending message. Response: %@", responseObject);
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error sending message: %@", error);
 }];
```

I am able to send attachments using curl, e.g.:

```
curl -s "https://api:key-
[redacted]@api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox[redacted].mailgun.org/messages" \
-F from=[redacted]@gmail.com \
-F to=[redacted]@gmail.com \
-F subject='Check this out!' \
-F text='LOL' \
-F attachment=@"lolcat.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to send attachments from within your iOS application using mail gun:

```
Mailgun *mailgun = [Mailgun clientWithDomain:@"yourdomain.com" apiKey:@"key"];

MGMessage *message = [MGMessage messageFrom:@"Someone <your.address@yourdomain.com>"
                                         to:@"Someone else <someone@else.com>"
                                    subject:@"Hello"
                                       body:@"This is a test email."];

[message addAttachment:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"filePath"] withName:@"fileName" type:@"fileType"];

[mailgun sendMessage:message success:^(NSString *messageId) {
    NSLog(@"Message %@ sent successfully!", messageId);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error sending message. The error was: %@", [error userInfo]);
}];
```